# Kubernetes - found invalid field spec Error

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml

Getting the following error while trying create a POD in kubernetes.

```
# kubectl create -f nginx-deployment-prod.yaml 
error: error validating "nginx-deployment-prod.yaml": error validating data: found invalid field spec for v1.ObjectMeta; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

The YAML file is as below :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: nginx-deployment-prod
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx-deployment-prod
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            image: "nginx:1.7.9"
            name: nginx-deployment-prod
            ports:
          - 
            containerPort: 80
```

Checked the YAML, if it's valid or not using http://www.yamllint.com/ ; Please let me know how can I get this resolved.

Comment: I see the answer below already but here is the link that converts yaml to JSON to figure out the issue https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had an issue with formatting your yaml file: `spec` should be on the same level as `metadata`.

Correct `nginx-deployment-prod.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: nginx-deployment-prod
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx-deployment-prod
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - name: nginx-deployment-prod
          image: "nginx:1.7.9"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```